# Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for test==1.0 from file:///home/ubuntu/sample/test-1.0.tar.gz

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install, egg

I get the following error when installing a package using pip
"Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for test==1.0 from file:///home/ubuntu/sample/test-1.0.tar.gz"

My setup.py is as follows:

```
from setuptools.command.install import install
from setuptools import setup

class Install(install):
    def run(self):
        install.do_egg_install(self)
        print "test....."
setup(
    name="test",
    version="1.0",
    cmdclass={
      'install': Install
    },
    install_requires=[
      "somepackage == 5.0"
    ]
)
```

Does anyone know what causes the warning?

Comment: When using `virtualenv==15.1.0 pip==9.0.1 wheel==0.29.0 setuptools==28.8.0`. Weird, this error can be solved with `python setup.py bdist_egg`. However, I found another issue by executing `python setup.py bdist_wheel` right after another error appears. Where `/Users/jmunsch/Desktop/dev/scraps/venv_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py(451)check_site_dir()` fails with `TEST FAILED: build/bdist.macosx-10.11-x86_64/wheel/ does NOT support .pth files`

Comment: also tried `python setup.py sdist && pip install dist/test-1.0.tar.gz` I suppose this might just be an issue with my machine, and I didn't test it with ubuntu.

Comment: just tested with ubuntu, after some snooping I found that both on my mac and ubuntu instances `test` installed, but the error related to this check still fails: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/easy_install.py#L442-L468 and uninstalling the egg is located in the wrong directory, or doesn't exist where it expects to find it.

Comment: The warning is one issue.  Another issue is after installing, if I upgrade it using the command sudo pip install test-2.0.tar.gz, it uninstalls 'test', removes the egg file and complains about missing egg file 1.0. Why does it look for version 1.0 egg file after uninstalling it?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with `user site` or where/how the `site-packages` are defined.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced install.do_egg_install(self) with install.run(self) and the warning goes away.